# MySql how to count rows in 1 command

Tags: mysql, select, count

Hey i got a table with workers and number of department they work at and i need to show the amount of departments , is there a way to do this in 1 select command? 
I been trying to use Count and group by but all i manage to show is either total amount of workers or total amount of workers per department. 
p.s  I will explain alittle better with a simple version , i got a table something like

```
Name / department 

john     5
jerry    4
josh     4
erik     1
```

in this case i need to get  somehting like  :
amount_of_departments 
3

if i use  count(*) as amount_of_departments  from ... group by department  i get
1
2
1
or if i use count(*) amount_of_departments from ....  i get 
4
if it possible then i am just lacking some basic sql knowledge since i am a starter : X

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do that with one command. Without knowing your table schema specific help is pretty difficult though, don't you think? The `DISTINCT` keyword is probably part of one solution, and the `GROUP BY` keyword is probably part of another -- I see you've used that but failed, but that certainly doesn't mean it's automatic failure. Present enough information (what you have, what you've tried, why your trials failed, etc) and you'll get enough response to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct department)
from table t;
```